# Close temporary workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I picked up this code from the web. It merges several Excel files to single file (each in separate sheets).

**The files the DATA is imported from don't automatically close**. This means that I need to manually close 8-10 files and "Do not Save" them, and that takes lots of time. What is the missing code?

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineExcelFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sDelimiter = "|"

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.*xl*), *.*xl*", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Excel Files to Open")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

x = 1
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
wkbTemp.Close (False)
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
  Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
  Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
  Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
  Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
x = x + 1

While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    With wkbAll
        wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
          Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
          ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
          Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
          Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
          Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
    End With
    x = x + 1
Wend

ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wkbAll = Nothing
Set wkbTemp = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wkbTemp.Close False` should close the workbook without saving it.

But another question is why do you process the first file outside the `While` loop? I see no reason for this. Therefore we can shorten that code to:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CombineExcelFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.*xl*), *.*xl*", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Excel Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            wkbTemp.Close False
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

#### Some Important Notes

- I recommend to avoid `ActiveWorkbook` if possible because it is not a defined workbook but any workbook that is active at just this moment. Also note that there is a difference between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` (which is a defined workbook. It is the workbook the code runs at this point).*
- Another thing is that `.Worksheets(x)` can be, but not necessarily must be the actually moved worksheet. I would say because you move the new sheet after the last sheet you also need to access the last sheet here: `.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)`.
- Also there is a difference between using `Sheets` and `Worksheets`. The `Sheets` collection contains worksheets but also charts etc, but the `Worksheets` collection only contains worksheets. Therefore you should decide which one is correct, I recommend always to use `Worksheets` unless you really need `Sheets`.
- And I see no need for setting the variables to nothing.

  ```
  Set wkbAll = Nothing
  Set wkbTemp = Nothing
  ```

  If I'm not totally wrong then Excel does this automatically when the procedure ends.